# Can I use the \LaTex logo using the XeLaTex compiler?

Tags: compiler-errors, latex, xelatex

I want to use the \LaTex logo for a XeLatex template that I am using. I get the following error:

! Undefined control sequence \LaTex

I think this is a dumb question but I didn't find any suitable answer searching online. Please tell me if you need more specific information, I didn't include it because I think the question is really simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The LaTeX logo is produced using `\LaTeX`:

[image]

It's formal definition, from the [LaTeX kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) is given by prepending `La` to the default `\TeX` logo:

```
\def\TeX{T\kern-.1667em\lower.5ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX\@}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\LaTeX}{L\kern-.36em%
        {\sbox\z@ T%
         \vbox to\ht\z@{\hbox{\check@mathfonts
                              \fontsize\sf@size\z@
                              \math@fontsfalse\selectfont
                              A}%
                        \vss}%
        }%
        \kern-.15em%
        \TeX}
```

Also see [How to write (La)TeX (with parentheses) [or any other TeX-related logo]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11095/5764).

Comment: thank you so much!, I didn't notice that I was using an 'x' instead of an 'X'. I thought the error might be because I was compiling with XeLaTex instead of PdfLaTex. That is why I did not find anything suitable in Internet, the question was dumber than I thought u_u